# Ruby app running under JVM

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking for a way to pack Ruby (eventually Ruby on Rails) apps as jar/war files so that I can leverage Ruby syntax and in the same time require only Java environment for running the app.

I've surfed internet, have seen JRuby, RubyFlux, ruby2java, but still miss a full picture on how these tools work and whether they are the same thing or not. So I'd like to ask you to shed some light on:

- available tools
- whether they are just interpreters of Ruby code or they pack java app and you need only simple JRE installed further on
- stability of the tools (e.g. RubyFlux looks to be on a kick-off stage)
- possible problems while using these tools

Comment: This question's a little broad, making it rather difficult to answer. I suggest doing a little more research into each of their functionalities and uses - see if it matches your desired specs.

Comment: I just need an overview of tools and principles, do not require too deep explanation.

Comment: I think it's a fair question. I know I had to do some digging to find these answers myself a while back.

Comment: Exactly! When you're facing a totally new thing, you'd like to have an overview first before choosing your way.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for [Warbler](https://github.com/jruby/warbler). This will package your [JRuby](http://jruby.org/) app into a .war file. JRuby is an implementation of the Ruby interpreter that runs in the JVM.

I've not used warbler, but JRuby is pretty stable. The only "problems" are lack of C-extensions and slower startup time, but these are usually not showstoppers.